# Why can I not open a unit test in C#?

Tags: c#

I am taking a course on C# programming and I want to add a Unit Test to my already existing solution. I right click on the solution and then I go to Add and then there should be an option to add a **Unit Test**.

This is not the case on my Visual Studio. When I click on Add another menu pops up and New Item..., Existing Item..., ..., Class, Component but no were does it say that I can add a United Test.

There is really no code to post.

**Question: How to add a Unit Test to my solution so that I can test each method?**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You want to add a Unit Test Project.  right click your solution -> Add new Project.  search for Unit test project.  add that.  it will include all the references you need to create a unit testable class.  I think it will also create a sample for you as well.

EDIT:

Hmm from the looks of it you don't have an actual solution. you just opened a project file. do you have a file with a .sln extension in the same folder?

if not:

File -> New Project -> create a new project with the same name.  This will create an actual solution file.  you can then "Add Existing Poject" to add your original project back to the new solution.

At this point you should be able to right click the solution.  which will be the root of your solution explorer. and "Add New Project" -> Add unit test project.

Comment: I tried opening a New Project -> with the same name and it did not work. So I created a whole new console application and I still to not see the actual solution, just a C# Project file. What am I doing wrong here?